# Compare file content of two files in two different directories

Tags: python, list

I have multiple files with same name in two directory. How to compare each one with the other line by line ( i.e compare file1 in dir1 with file2 in dir2 line by line if they have same name:
So far I have:

```
dir1 = "dir1"

dir2 = "/dir2"

files1 = os.listdir(dir1)

files2 = os.listdir(dir2)

for x in files2:

    for y in files1:

        if x == y:

            #compare element of each line for e.g in file 1 I have list:
            1, 2, 3
            2, 4, 6
            #file2 I have another list:
            2, 4, 3
            2, 4, 6
            #if first two numbers are equal then output the entire list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating over every file in *dir1* against every file in *dir2*, you can just iterate over the files in *dir1* and check if that file exists in *dir2* if only interested in the files having the same name.

Then do something like this to compare matching files.

```python
import os

dir1 = "dir1"
dir2 = "dir2"

for file in os.listdir(dir1):
    file2 = os.path.join(dir2, file1)
    if os.path.exists(file2):
        file1 = os.path.join(dir1, file)
        print(file)
        with open(file1, "r") as f1, open(file2, "r") as f2:
            # compare file1 and file2 line by line
            # add your logic here to compare the two files
            same = True
            while True:
                line1 = f1.readline()
                line2 = f2.readline()
                if line1 != line2:
                    same = False
                    break
                if len(line1) == 0:
                    break
            if same:
                print("files are same")
            else:
                print("files are different")
```